# jquery auto complete textbox is not working with update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Update panel is updated once jquery unloaded how to reload again.
how to overcome the jquery with update panel

Update panel is updated once jquery unloaded how to reload again.
how to overcome the jquery with update panel

```
          <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Custom data and display</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(function () {
      var projects = [
  { "label": "AN-01", "actor": "Port Blair " },
  { "label": "AN-02", "actor": "Car Nicobar " },
  { "label": "AP-01", "actor": "Adilabad / Mancherial / Nirmal" },
  { "label": "AP-02", "actor": "Anantapur " },
  { "label": "AP-03", "actor": "Chittoor " },
  { "label": "AP-04", "actor": "Kadapa " },
  { "label": "AP-05", "actor": "East Godavari " },
  { "label": "AP-06", "actor": "Kakinada / Amalapuram / Rajahmundry" },
  { "label": "AP-07", "actor": "Guntur " }
      ];

      $("#lstRTO").autocomplete({
          source: projects,
          select: function (event, ui) {
              $("#lstRTO").val(ui.item.label);
              return false;
          }
      })
      .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
          return $("<li>")
            .append("<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong> / " + item.actor + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
      };
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body >
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel24" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                                            <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="lstRTO" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control wid-mob lim-size" type="text" MaxLength="5" max="5" placeholder="RTO Code"></asp:TextBox>
   </ContentTemplate>
                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

   </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: The update panel replaces the content of update panel on its update this means you have new content in the update panel. So the solution is to rebind the jQuery events.

Answer (score 2):

Rebind the jquery events at event Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            initializer();
        });


        var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();


        prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
            //you need to re-bind your jquery events here
            initializer();
        });
        function initializer() {
          var projects = [
  { "label": "AN-01", "actor": "Port Blair " },
  { "label": "AN-02", "actor": "Car Nicobar " },
  { "label": "AP-01", "actor": "Adilabad / Mancherial / Nirmal" },
  { "label": "AP-02", "actor": "Anantapur " },
  { "label": "AP-03", "actor": "Chittoor " },
  { "label": "AP-04", "actor": "Kadapa " },
  { "label": "AP-05", "actor": "East Godavari " },
  { "label": "AP-06", "actor": "Kakinada / Amalapuram / Rajahmundry" },
  { "label": "AP-07", "actor": "Guntur " }
      ];

      $("#lstRTO").autocomplete({
          source: projects,
          select: function (event, ui) {
              $("#lstRTO").val(ui.item.label);
              return false;
          }
      })
      .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
          return $("<li>")
            .append("<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong> / " + item.actor + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
      };


        }


    </script>
```

Please refer this for more details [_endRequest()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: same problem is violating                                                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755104/jquery-auto-complete-textbox-is-not-working-with-update-panel-using-asp-net