# jquery auto complete textbox is not working with update panel using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Unable to get result Update panel is updated once jquery unloaded how to reload again. How to overcome the jquery with update panel

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TPAppl.WebForm1" %>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Custom data and display</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        initializer();
    });


    var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();


    prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
        //you need to re-bind your jquery events here
        initializer();
    });
    function initializer() {
        var projects = [
{ "label": "AN-01", "actor": "Port Blair " },
{ "label": "AN-02", "actor": "Car Nicobar " }
        ];

        $("#lstRTO").autocomplete({
            source: projects,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#lstRTO").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
              .append("<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong> / " + item.actor + "</a>")
              .appendTo(ul);
        };


    }


</script>
</head>
 <body runat="server">
      <form runat="server">
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">     </asp:ScriptManager>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
              <input id="lstRTO">
          </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </form>
</body>
```

C# Code Like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TPAppl
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text+"123";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please find the previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750741/jquery-auto-complete-textbox-is-not-working-with-update-panel

Answer (score 3):

Change the way you write id of your textbox

from:

```
 $("#lstRTO").autocomplete({
```

To:

```
 $("[id*=lstRTO]").autocomplete({
```

It will work 100%.

Answer (score 1):

It will help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            $(function () {
                initializer();
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```